# psql: how to group similar consecutive events on a table with timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I'm facing a problem on a table of events.

I have enter and exit events on a two column table and I need to get the interval of in_time.
The problem is that the sensor device (a neuronl network on camera which is still on developement) is not that precise and sometimes I get more than one enter-event and then just one exit event, so the table ends up like the following.

| ts | event | device |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-28 00:00:00 | enter | 1 |
| 2021-04-28 00:01:00 | exit | 1 |
| 2021-04-28 00:02:00 | enter | 1 |
| 2021-04-28 00:04:00 | enter | 1 |
| 2021-04-28 00:06:00 | enter | 2 |
| 2021-04-28 00:08:00 | exit | 1 |
| 2021-04-28 00:10:00 | enter | 2 |
| 2021-04-28 00:11:00 | enter | 2 |
| 2021-04-28 00:14:00 | exit | 2 |

The criteria I want to meet is interval = exit - first enter event of the batch.
My idea is to get the following table and then use `lag (ts,-1)` to get the substraction.

| ts | event | device |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-28 00:00:00 | enter | 1 |
| 2021-04-28 00:01:00 | exit | 1 |
| 2021-04-28 00:02:00 | enter | 1 |
| 2021-04-28 00:08:00 | exit | 1 |
| 2021-04-28 00:06:00 | enter | 2 |
| 2021-04-28 00:14:00 | exit | 2 |

Any idea on how to get this table?
Thank you!

PS:
The real table uses uuid as key, not a numerical value.

PS2:
The final result I want would be this one

| occupancy | device |
| --- | --- |
| 00:01:00 | 1 |
| 00:06:00 | 1 |
| 00:08:00 | 2 |

I think I can get it from the second one, but if there is another path I'm not seeing that can obtain this table from the first one without going trought the second one, it would be interesting to know,

Thank you again!!

Answer (score 2):

step 1:
use the window function `lag` to check if the prior event (ordered by `ts`) for a given sensor is distinct from the event in the current row, and keep only the rows that have distinct events.

```sql
with sensor_events (ts, event_name, device) as ( 
values
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:00:00'  ,'enter',   1),
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:01:00'  ,'exit',    1),
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:02:00'  ,'enter',   1),
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:04:00'  ,'enter',   1),
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:06:00'  ,'enter',   2),
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:08:00'  ,'exit',    1),
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:10:00'  ,'enter',   2),
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:11:00'  ,'enter',   2),
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:14:00'  ,'exit',    2)
)
, distinct_events AS (
select *
  , lag(event_name) over 
    (partition by device order by ts) 
    is distinct from event_name 
    AS is_distinct_event
from sensor_events
)
select ts, event_name, device
from distinct_events
where is_distinct_event
```

outputs:

```
ts                          event_name  device
2021-04-28T00:00:00.000Z    enter            1
2021-04-28T00:01:00.000Z    exit             1
2021-04-28T00:02:00.000Z    enter            1
2021-04-28T00:08:00.000Z    exit             1
2021-04-28T00:06:00.000Z    enter            2
2021-04-28T00:14:00.000Z    exit             2
```

step 2: use the lag function again to calculate the time delta between exit & enter events.

```sql
with sensor_events (ts, event_name, device) as ( 
values
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:00:00'  ,'enter',   1),
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:01:00'  ,'exit',    1),
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:02:00'  ,'enter',   1),
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:04:00'  ,'enter',   1),
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:06:00'  ,'enter',   2),
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:08:00'  ,'exit',    1),
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:10:00'  ,'enter',   2),
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:11:00'  ,'enter',   2),
  (timestamp '2021-04-28 00:14:00'  ,'exit',    2)
)
, distinct_events AS (
select *
  , lag(event_name) over 
    (partition by device order by ts) 
    is distinct from event_name 
    AS is_distinct_event
from sensor_events
)
, occupancy AS (
  select 
    ts - lag(ts) over w occupancy
  , event_name
  , lag(event_name) over w last_event_name
  , device
  from distinct_events
  where is_distinct_event
  window w as (partition by device order by ts)
)
select 
occupancy, device
from occupancy
where event_name = 'exit' 
  and last_event_name = 'enter'
```

this will output the table you are after.